# Graph API delta query returning unchanged items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

(I am not sure if this question qualifies for StackOverflow topics but still posting here as I saw similar questions.)

I am seeing a weird issue where sometimes the delta query returns items that are not changed. (This is not seen very frequently.) I am querying OneDrive for changes since the last download.

For example, the following delta query returned me an item (DSC_0065.JPG) that was not changed.

Delta query:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!Pcaiw06w-kSGWLjMnEbRKDysPjWgxmVIsBZ0VKCCAn-Nh63ehP3RRLTY1UUJRrZx/root/delta?token=MzslMjM0OyUyMzE7MztkZWFkODc4ZC1mZDg0LTQ0ZDEtYjRkOC1kNTQ1MDk0NmI2NzE7NjM3NzY3MzgyNDMwNjAwMDAwOzc0MDczMTMwMjslMjM7JTIzOyUyMzA

Output:

```html
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)",
"@odata.deltaLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!Pcaiw06w-kSGWLjMnEbRKDysPjWgxmVIsBZ0VKCCAn-Nh63ehP3RRLTY1UUJRrZx/root/delta?token=MzslMjM0OyUyMzE7MztkZWFkODc4ZC1mZDg0LTQ0ZDEtYjRkOC1kNTQ1MDk0NmI2NzE7NjM3NzY3OTc3Mjc1NjMwMDAwOzc0MTAxMDA2NjslMjM7JTIzOyUyMzA",
"value": [
{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
"createdDateTime": "2020-10-24T18:41:32Z",
"id": "012GIYIB56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-02T16:35:37Z",
"name": "root",
"webUrl": "https://vx2-my.sharepoint.com/personal/abc_xyz_vx2_onmicrosoft_com/Documents",
"size": 61213695,
"parentReference": {
"driveId": "b!Pcaiw06w-kSGWLjMnEbRKDysPjWgxmVIsBZ0VKCCAn-Nh63ehP3RRLTY1UUJRrZx",
"driveType": "business"
},
"fileSystemInfo": {
"createdDateTime": "2020-10-24T18:41:32Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-02T16:35:37Z"
},
"folder": {
"childCount": 18
},
"root": {}
},
{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.driveItem",
"createdDateTime": "2022-01-02T16:35:32Z",
"eTag": ""{A16CFB31-B9ED-4FD9-907E-4EF289FFBEDC},1"",
"id": "012GIYIBZR7NWKD3NZ3FHZA7SO6KE77PW4",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-02T16:35:32Z",
"name": "DSC_0065.JPG",
"webUrl": "https://vx2-my.sharepoint.com/personal/abc_xyz_vx2_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/DSC_0065.JPG",
"cTag": ""c:{A16CFB31-B9ED-4FD9-907E-4EF289FFBEDC},1"",
"size": 474499,
"createdBy": {
"user": {
"email": "abc.xyz@vx2.onmicrosoft.com",
"id": "9af20ae1-ebbb-4e28-a733-6238ea79432f",
"displayName": "abc xyz"
}
},
"lastModifiedBy": {
"user": {
"email": "abc.xyz@vx2.onmicrosoft.com",
"id": "9af20ae1-ebbb-4e28-a733-6238ea79432f",
"displayName": "abc xyz"
}
},
"parentReference": {
"driveId": "b!Pcaiw06w-kSGWLjMnEbRKDysPjWgxmVIsBZ0VKCCAn-Nh63ehP3RRLTY1UUJRrZx",
"driveType": "business",
"id": "012GIYIB56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
"path": "/drives/b!Pcaiw06w-kSGWLjMnEbRKDysPjWgxmVIsBZ0VKCCAn-Nh63ehP3RRLTY1UUJRrZx/root:"
},
"file": {
"mimeType": "image/jpeg",
"hashes": {
"quickXorHash": "2W+jVZHuhuJuMkvJhHefNrBUztE="
}
},
"fileSystemInfo": {
"createdDateTime": "2022-01-02T16:35:32Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-01-02T16:35:32Z"
},
"image": {
"height": 1000,
"width": 1500
},
"photo": {
"takenDateTime": "2018-12-01T08:00:50.4Z"
}
}
]
}
```

Has anyone seen his kind of issue? Please let me know.

Comment: Is the JSON payload identical between the last time you got it and this time? While the contents of the file didn't change, it's possible the metadata about the file did (including if the file was shared, or if something like behind-the-scenes image recognition ran).

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. This was a test I ran where there was no change in data. I ran two delta queries with just 1-minute gap in between. And this is my test tenant so no possibility of any changes happening in the background.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue from last couple of days. No change in share-point drive but still while processing delta, the file appearing as a change.